# TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined using react router (express)

Tags: reactjs, express, typeerror

I have the following class using React with express.

I'm trying to call another method from the method `getOne` which is declared in a route. But when I call the route for method `getOne` I have this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createFromSystem' of undefined
    at /home/joao/tcc/efono-api/src/controllers/ContrastiveAnalysis/phonetic_inventory.controller.ts:193:42
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/joao/tcc/efono-api/src/controllers/ContrastiveAnalysis/phonetic_inventory.controller.ts:5:58)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

How can I solve this problem? Anyone can help? I already try another things without sucess. I'm newby with react.

The class:

```
import { Router, Response } from 'express';
import { AuthenticatedRequest } from '@interfaces/AuthenticatedRequest';

import authenticationMiddleware from '@middlewares/authentication.middleware';
import authorizationMiddleware from '@middlewares/authorization.middleware';
import validationMiddleware from '@middlewares/validation.middleware';
import asyncWrapper from '@utils/asyncWrapper';

import Controller from '@interfaces/Controller';
import PhoneticInventoryModel, { PhoneticInventory, Plosiva, Fricativa, Africada, Nasal, Glide, Outro, LiquidaLateral, LiquidaNaoLateral, PhoneticInventoryClass } from '@models/ContrastiveAnalysis/phonetic_inventory.model';
import PhonemaRealizatonModel, { PhonemaRealization } from '@models/ContrastiveAnalysis/phonema_realization.model';
import { Role } from '@models/user.model';
import { NotFoundException } from '@exceptions/NotFoundException';

class PhoneticInventoryController implements Controller {
    public path = '/phoneticInventory';
    public router = Router();

    constructor() {
        this.initializeRoutes();
        // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
        this.createFromSystem = this.createFromSystem.bind(this);
    }

    private initializeRoutes() {
        this.router.get(
            `${this.path}/getOne/:evaluationId/:targetWordId`,
            asyncWrapper(authenticationMiddleware),
            asyncWrapper(this.getOne)
        );
    }

    private async getOne(request: AuthenticatedRequest<any>, response: Response) {
        const evaluationId = request.params.evaluationId;
        const targetWordId = request.params.targetWordId;

        if (!evaluationId || !targetWordId) {
            return Promise.reject(new NotFoundException());
        }

        const evaluation = await PhoneticInventoryModel.findOne({ evaluationId, targetWordId });

       if (!evaluation) {
            const otherEval = await this.createFromSystem(evaluationId, targetWordId);
            if (!otherEval) {
                return Promise.reject(new NotFoundException());
            }
            response.status(200).send(otherEval);
        } else {
            response.status(200).send(evaluation);
        }
    }

    private async createFromSystem(evaluationId: string, targetWordId: string): Promise<PhoneticInventory> {
        console.log("Calculating phonetic inventory for " + evaluationId + " (" + targetWordId + ")...");

        if (!evaluationId || !targetWordId) {
            return null;
        }

        const phonemaRealization = await PhonemaRealizatonModel.findOne({ evaluationId, targetWordId });

        if (!phonemaRealization) {
            return null;
        }

        const phoneticInventory: PhoneticInventory = {
            plosiva, fricativa, africada, nasal, glide, outro, liquida_lateral, liquida_nao_lateral
        };
        return phoneticInventory;
    }
}

export default PhoneticInventoryController;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please bind getOne function

```
constructor() {
    this.initializeRoutes();
    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.createFromSystem = this.createFromSystem.bind(this);
    this.getOne = this.getOne.bind(this);
}
```

or please use the arrow function.

```
private getOne = async(request: AuthenticatedRequest<any>, response: Response) => {
    ...
}
private createFromSystem = async (evaluationId: string, targetWordId: string): Promise<PhoneticInventory> => {
    ...
}
```

Comment: didn't work :( another idea?

Comment: Did you try with arrow function?

Comment: yes. For now I'm using a different route for each method, then I have to call them outside of the API in the correct order. Just a workaround, but I'd like to know how can I call a method inside of another one, like the example.